# Flutter: Extract Rect from image by coordinates

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I would like to extract a rect from an image.

The rect is given by the following:

```
final rect = Rect.fromLTRB(left, top, right, bottom);
```

I have an Android background and in Android I did this:

```
private fun Rect.toBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, left, top, width(), height())
```

I tried out this image library: https://pub.dev/packages/image but this is not working properly.

Now, is it possible to achieve the same in Dart/Flutter?

Kind regards

Comment: Have a look at this: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_image

Comment: Thats great! Thank you so much. You can post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this package: [flutter_native_image](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_image).

It provides a cropImage function, which could be what you are looking for.

`File croppedFile = await FlutterNativeImage.cropImage(file.path, originX, originY, width, height);`